# What is the difference between passing a single column to j and selecting the same column from a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that contains `name` and `class`. Each `name` belongs to one `class`. Here is a sample dataset.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(name = c("John","Smith","Jane","Ruby","Emerald","Jasmine","Tulip"),
             class = c(1,2,3))
```

I want to create a column which contains all the students in the class that a person belongs to. This is how I'm doing it and it works.

```
DT[, class.students := paste(.SD), .SDcols = "name", by = "class"]
```

I'm trying to understand why the following doesn't work, i.e., it does not evaluate the function over the list of all `name`'s in the group (it returns just the `name` value of the row in the created column)

```
DT[, class.students := paste(name), by = "class"]
```

Especially when the code below with `max` works as expected, i.e., it evaluates over all elements in the group and returns the same value for each group.

```
DT[, class.students := max(name), by = "class"]
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: `max` is a bad example as it doesn't work in the first way, using `.SDcols`, but I hope what I am trying to convey is clear.

Comment: Your `DT` data.table creation have unequal elements in `name` and `class`.

Comment: @akrun, that is by design. I wanted to take advantage of recycling in its creation.

Comment: Ok, it gives me some warning, so i thought you missed something there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.SD` is a `list`, so it returns an output which may not be desired one (if we check the `str`).   As a small example

```
paste(list(letters[1:3])) #not the desirable output
#[1] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"

paste(letters[1:3]) #did not change anything
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

However, `paste` also have `sep` and `collapse` as arguments

```
paste(letters[1:3], collapse=", ")
#[1] "a, b, c"
```

---

Using the OP's example,

```
DT[, class.students := paste(name, collapse=", "), by = class]
```

We would recommend to apply a function directly to `.SD`, but if there is a single column, we can convert the `list` to `vector` either by `[[` or converting with `unlist` etc.

```
DT[,  class.students := paste(unlist(.SD), collapse=", "), by = class]
```

Or

```
DT[, class.students := paste(.SD[[1]], collapse=", "), by = class]
```

If we check the `str(DT)` from all the above, it would be the same

---

Regarding the optimal way to apply functions on `.SD` - as we already mentioned that it is a `list`.  and `.SD` is useful when there are more number of columns.  As in `data.frame`, when there are multiple column, we loop through the columns with `lapply` and proceed

```
DT[, class.students := lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=", "), by = class]
```

We can also specify the `.SDcols` if there are only a subset of columns are used.  Here, in the example, there are only two columns, so `.SDcols` is not needed.

```
str(DT)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ name          : chr  "John" "Smith" "Jane" "Ruby" ...
# $ class         : num  1 2 3 1 2 3 1
# $ class.students: chr  "John, Ruby, Tulip" "Smith, Emerald" "Jane, Jasmine" "John, Ruby, Tulip" ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Your example using `collapse` was just what I needed. And to answer my original question, `.SD` returning a `list`, and the column `name` by itself, without using `.SDcols` returning a character vector is exactly what had stumped me. This helped me figure it out as well: `DT[, class.students := str(name), by="class"]` vs `DT[, class.students := str(.SD), .SDcols="name", by="class"]`.

Comment: @Naumz Thank you for the additional checks.  THe `.SD` means `Subset of Data.table`, so it is basically a `data.table` and `data.table` and `data.frame` are all `list` with special attributes